# After Ubuntu kernel upgrade in Virtual Box Genymotion Virtual machine Host-Only Adapter is missing, attempt to create a new one is unsuccessful

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 My Virtual Box was running perfectly fine. But then I upgraded my kernel and rebooted the computer.

Now when I am trying to start my Virtual Machine I am getting the following error -

```
Could not start the machine Samsung Galaxy S10 because the following physical network interfaces were not found:

vboxnet3 (adapter 1)

You can either change the machine's network settings or stop the machine.
```

[image]

If I click on Change Network Settings, the under `Host-Only Adapter` there is no `Name` that can be selected.

[image]

Now, if I click on cancel I get the following error -

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Samsung Galaxy S10.

Nonexistent host networking interface, name 'vboxnet3' (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

[image]

If I go to File -> Preferences -> Network there is a tab having only `NAT network` and no `Host-Only Adapter` tab.

[image]

If I go to File -> Host Network Manager -> Create a new network `vboxnet0` -> Enable -> Properties -> Configure Adapter Automatically -> Apply

[image]

I am getting the following error -

```
Failed to save host network interface parameter.

Callee RC: NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED (0x80004001)
```

[image]

At this point under the Virtual Machine -> Settings -> Network, below `Host-Only Adapter` the Name `vboxnet0` is present, but still the problem persists.

[image]

I have also tried from terminal -

`sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`

and got the following output -

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /lib/modules/5.8.0-36-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /lib/modules/5.8.0-36-generic: No such file or directory
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
```

UPDATE:

My Virtual Machine Samsung Galaxy S10 has not been created directly from Virtual Box but by Genymotion Android Emulator Creator.

The directory VirtualMachines under my home directory is empty. The Virtual Machine is rather present in the location `~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Samsung Galaxy S10`

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the content of your *VirtualBox.xml* for the VM

Comment: @Ramhound updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.

In terminal I had to run -

`sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`

Then in Virtual Machine I had to do -

If I go to File -> Host Network Manager -> Create a new network vboxnet0 -> Enable -> Properties -> Configure Adapter Automatically -> Apply

[image]

and ignore any error prompt.

Then in file manager I had to go to

`~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Samsung Galaxy S10`

[image]

Then I double clicked on the icon -

`Samsung Galaxy S10.vbox`

A terminal opened and did some job.

Then I closed the terminal. After this action everything was working fine and I could start my Virtual Machine from Genymotion successfully.